# TypeError when running in python 3.6 - the object not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am running this code in the python interactive and getting the error as follow 
"TypeError: 'int' object is not callable" I am trying to learn python.

```
def getNum(n,div):
    for i in range(n):
        if i % div == 0:
            yield i
DIVIDER = 7
RANGE = 50

print ([n for n in getNum(RANGE,DIVIDER)])
```

Comment: The code you've posted runs fine for me. Is it possible you defined a variable named `range` somewhere earlier in your code or in something that you didn't show us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you got could either be happening at:

```
for i in range(n):
```

or

```
print ([n for n in getNum(RANGE,DIVIDER)])
```

Somehow the interpreter thinks that `getNum` or `range` is an `int`.

It is likely that the error comes from `range` and not from `getNum`. So, if you run the following, your problem should be solved:

```
import builtins # import builtins

def getNum(n,div):
    for i in builtins.range(n): # use the range from builtins
        if i % div == 0:
            yield i
DIVIDER = 7
RANGE = 50

print ([n for n in getNum(RANGE,DIVIDER)])
```

Comment: Thanks. It works now. So I am now using the import builtins.

Comment: My pleasuse. If you think that is sufficient, feel free to accept this answer.